# Ошибка работы с MySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Делал оплату сервиса через купюру монеты в бд `money`, присвоение дней `timePrins` к сервису и активация `acivPrins`. Возникла ошибка ни разу не встречал.

**Вот ошибка:**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1'' at line 1
```

**Вот мой индийский код** *(Если кто то поможет сократить и превратить в нормальный буду рад)*:

```
<?php
include ('db.php');

session_start();

if (empty($_COOKIE['id'])) {
    exit("<html><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=http://dedaster.com/'></html>");
}
else {
    $COID = $_COOKIE['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ListDB` WHERE id='$COID'", $db) or die(mysql_error());
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $presult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Prins` WHERE idAkk='$COID'", $db) or die(mysql_error());
    $pmyrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($presult);
    if (!empty($_POST['serv']) or !empty($_POST['sell']) or ($_POST['serv'] = '1')) {
        $s1 = '20';
        $s2 = '100';
        $s3 = '180';
        $s4 = '550';
        $s5 = '1500';
        $s6 = '6500';
        if ($_POST['sell'] == '1') {
            $r = $myrow['money'] - $s1;
            $t = '1';
        }
        else
        if ($_POST['sell'] == '2') {
            $t = '5';
            $r = $myrow['money'] - $s2;
        }
        else
        if ($_POST['sell'] == '3') {
            $r = $myrow['money'] - $s3;
            $t = '10';
        }
        else
        if ($_POST['sell'] == '4') {
            $t = '30';
            $r = $myrow['money'] - $s4;
        }
        else
        if ($_POST['sell'] == '5') {
            $r = $myrow['money'] - $s5;
            $t = '100';
        }
        else
        if ($_POST['sell'] == '6') {
            $r = $myrow['money'] - $s6;
            $t = '365';
        }

        if ($r < 0) {
            exit("<html><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='4; URL=http://dedaster.com/'><body>Error</body></html>");
        }
        else {
            $r = $r + $myrow['money'];
            $t = $t + $myrowp['timePrins'];
            $re = '1';
            $result4 = mysql_query("UPDATE `ListDB` SET money='$r'' WHERE id='$COID' ", $db) or die(mysql_error());
            $result3 = mysql_query("UPDATE `Prins` SET timePrins='$t', acivPrins='$re' WHERE idAkk='$COID' ", $db) or die(mysql_error());
            exit("<html><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=http://dedaster.com/'></html>");
        }
    }

    exit("<html><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=http://dedaster.com/'></html>");
}

?>
```

**Вопрос:**  Как убрать ошибку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Возникла ошибка ни разу не встречал =)". Гениально! Работать с SQL, и ни разу в жизни не ошибиться в синтаксисе запроса?

```
UPDATE `ListDB` SET money='$r'' WHERE id='$COID'
```

Уберите лишнюю '.

Comment: Такой ошибки не было